# Export all stream videos from stream on sharepoint to csv

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft365

We have not migrated from stream classic to stream on sharepoint yet.
But there has been a big load of videos recorded and uploaded to stream on sharepoint during last couple of month.

With version history activated for legal reasons, a video of lets say 140 where someone change transcription 10 times will grow to 1.4gb in no time.

I been looking for powershell script to find all stream on sharepoint videos which would list:
Video name, number of version, size and link to site/document library where it's stored.

I yet not been able to find a script like this neither from microsoft or anyone else.

Anyone made something similar to this? Even if it's only something simpler to build on that would work as well.

If not, any idea on how to do this in the smoothest way?

Comment: Have you checked out the `Stream migration page` from the SharePoint admin center? https://yourTenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/migration/stream